# The xpath for clicking edit button is not working in Selenium Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

**HTML Code:**

```
<button onclick="root.handleOnClick( document, this );" id="Edit_edit::0" 
title="Edit" name="Edit_edit::0" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default btn-sm cs-btn" 
type="button">Edit</button>
```

**XPath** which I used:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Edit']")).click();
```

Please help me to run this code.

Comment: use javascriptexecutor to click the button

Comment: You say you have the frames. Tell us what is the frame structure that holds your button? Is there just a frame that holds your button or frame that contains another frame that holds your button? Also show us frame html elements.

Comment: Your question is not clear and lacks essential details necessary to provide an good answer https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to click button.

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Edit']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.I tried it,but its not working.There is frames,forms in my working site.Whether we have to first write code for frames,forms.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a frame in the page you need to switch into the frame first and then you can access the button by using your xpath.

To switch into the frame use below command

```
driver.switchTo().Frame(id or class);
```